# Create table in Athena using all objects from multiple folders in S3 Bucket via Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-athena

My S3 Bucket has multiple sub-directories that store data for multiple websites based on the day.
example:
bucket/2020-01-03/website 1 and within this are where the csv's are stored.
I am able to create tables based on each of the objects but I want to create one consolidated table for all sub-directories/objects/data stored within the prefix bucket/2020-01-03 for all websites as well as all other dates.

I used the code below to create one table for

## Athena configuration

```
athena = boto3.client('athena',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY, 
region_name= 'us-west-2')
s3_input = 's3://bucket/2020-01-03/website1'

database = 'database1'
table = 'consolidated_table'
```

## Athena database and table definition

```
create_table = \

 """CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `%s.%s` (
  `website_id` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `user` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `action` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `date` string COMMENT 'from deserializer'
     )
     ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
     WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
     'escapeChar'='\\"', 'separatorChar'=','
     ) LOCATION '%s'
     TBLPROPERTIES (
  'skip.header.line.count'='1', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1576774420');""" % ( database, table, s3_input )

athena.start_query_execution(QueryString=create_table, 
WorkGroup = 'user_group',
QueryExecutionContext={'Database': 'database1'},
ResultConfiguration={'OutputLocation': 's3://aws-athena-query-results-5000-us-west-2'})
```

I also want to over-write this table with new data from S3 everytime I run it.

Comment: When you say overwrite you mean the existing file in s3 is modified with new records or it will be totally new data?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a consolidated table for the files from different "directories" on S3 only if all of them adhere the same data schema. As I can see from your `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE`, each file contains 4 columns `website_id`, `user`, `action` and `date`. So you can simply change `LOCATION` to point to the root of your S3 "directory structure"

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database1`.`consolidated_table` (
    `website_id` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
    `user` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
    `action` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
    `date` string COMMENT 'from deserializer'
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    'escapeChar'='\\"', 'separatorChar'=','
) 
LOCATION 's3://bucket' -- instead of restricting it to s3://bucket/2020-01-03/website1
TBLPROPERTIES (
    'skip.header.line.count'='1'
);
```

In this case, each Athena query would scan all files under `s3://bucket` location and you can use `website_id` and `date` in `WHERE` clause to filter results. However, if you have a lot of data you should consider [partitioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html). It will save you not only time to execute query but also money (see [this post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/))

> I also want to over-write this table with new data from S3 every time I run it.

I assume you mean, that every time you run Athena query, it should scan files on S3 even if they were added after you executed `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE`. Note, that `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` simply defines a meta information about you data, i.e. where it is located on S3, columns etc. Thus, query against table with `LOCATION 's3://bucket'` (w/o partitioning) will always include all your S3 files